# Finding Containers Using Docker VirtualBox

Tags: docker, kitematic

I'm new to Docker and I'm Running macOS Sierra. I have installed Docker and can get the  open Kitematic on localhost I can see my containers without issue and can access the site on localhost - when I switch to VirutalBox, my containers are no longer in Kitematic and I can't figure out how to access them in my browser.

Could anyone give me some insight on what to do here?

Comment: If you are talking about a VM running on localhost, then you would have to install docker there as well (probably a bad or useless idea).  If you are talking about being in the Kitematic container, that makes sense because you generally can't see containers from within other containers unless it is through network connections.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - I meant VirtualBox not VM

Comment: Still wonder why you would use virtual box when you are using Docker already.  Nothing wrong with containers instead of VM's, IMHO.

Comment: The lead dev is telling me I need to set up my container using a docker ip (begins with 192) and I can only get it working on localhost. He told me to use VirtualBox.

Comment: Ah!  I don't see how VirtualBox is going to do anything but add another layer of complexity to the networking.  Focus on networking models for docker, when you get closer, maybe ask a better question?  Also, Docker IP's generally start with 172.   192 is usually for Class C LAN's.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to get work, but when I enter the default docker IP nothing comes up. It only comes up running 127.0.0.1 (localhost).

Answer (score 0):

Your intention for getting the IP of your host(192.*) is unclear to me.

You can achieve this by simply adding the net flag in your docker instruction `'--net host'`

For more details go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170738/how-does-dockers-net-host-setting-work-and-how-can-i-do-something-similar-wi).

If your intention is to make your container available to everyone, then there is no need to do it. Everyone should be able to access your docker container by accessing your machine's ip followed by port number (http://192.168.x.x:xxxx)